# Test for open port before attempting HttpClient connection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

The various methods of the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193681.aspx) class (GetAsync etc.) take a Uri object or string and attempt to open a connection to the specified location. However it's very likely in my case that the remote host is not listening (the port is closed and will be actively refused; it's inside our LAN).

I'd rather not rely on catching an exception to handle this scenario, especially since these methods throw an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) which I'd then have to sift through.

Is there a better way to detect this scenario while still getting the benefits of the HttpClient class (the remote host is a WebApi service)? Should I check to see if the port is listening beforehand using something like TcpClient? Of course that involves a race condition between the calls. I'm hoping that the constructor overload that takes an HttpMessageHandler will help, but nothing in [WebRequestHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.aspx) is jumping out at me either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Socket.Connect(string host, int port)`

```
    private static bool TestForOpenHttpPort(string host)
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            s.Connect(host, 80);
            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            ((IDisposable)s).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Simple usage :

```
if (TestForOpenHttpPort("google.com"))
{
    // socket is open
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this still depends on catching an exception for program logic and it still has a race condition between when I check for the open port and when I attempt the connection. I'm still looking for a way to hook into the actual HTTP connection attempt and trap the failure there but if I can't find a way to do that I'll accept this answer...